# How to disable the transparent frame that is created when you are about to resize a window?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

When I'm about to resize a simple GUI created on Windows/c++

```
int APIENTRY wWinMain(_In_ HINSTANCE hInstance, _In_opt_ HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, _In_ LPWSTR lpCmdLine, _In_ int nCmdShow) {

    LoadStringW(hInstance, IDC_PROJECT2, szWindowClass, MAX_LOADSTRING);
    MyRegisterClass(hInstance);

    if (!InitInstance (hInstance, nCmdShow))
        return FALSE;

    HACCEL hAccelTable = LoadAccelerators(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDC_PROJECT2));

    MSG msg;
    while (GetMessage(&msg, nullptr, 0, 0)){
        if (!TranslateAccelerator(msg.hwnd, hAccelTable, &msg)) {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }
    }

    return (int) msg.wParam;
}
```

It creates a transparent rectangle showing where it will be expanded to:

[image: v]

I would like to disable it, as i'm working with a custom frameless GUI.

I tried searching for how this transparent rectangle is called or what WINAPI creates it, but I could not find it.

Appreciate any help on this.

Comment: That's the Aero Snap feature. (Not sure what it's called now that we no longer have an Aero theme.) It doesn't normally show when resizing a window, only when snapping a window. Without it, how would you expect the user to know what will happen to the window? Why would this be a problem for a custom frameless GUI? Your window still has *some kind of GUI*. If your window cannot be resized, then that option should be disabled, and then these snap hints will not be displayed, either.

Comment: @CodyGray this is how it look at my gui, as it have a lot of 'hacks' https://i.imgur.com/X5hz7ly.png, i just would like to get ride of this transparent thing.

Comment: Ah, I see. So the *real* problem is that the translucent rectangle doesn't match what appears to the user to be the actual rectangle of your window, right? This should be corrected by telling Windows what the actual bounds of your window are. Then, the hinting rectangle would use the correct bounds. Look into handling the `WM_NCCALCSIZE` message.

Answer (score 0):

Its principle is similar to that of sheet of glass.
[image]

Basically, sheet of glass expands to become a parent window, and the window being dragged is a layered window when the window touches the edge of the screen.

The system uses `SetLayeredWindowAttributes` to make sheet of glass transparent, and dragged windows are not affected by `WS_POPUP` parameter.

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/using-windows#using-layered-windows) explains how to achieve transparency and de-transparency.

*To make this window completely opaque again, remove the `WS_EX_LAYERED` bit by calling `SetWindowLong` and then ask the window to repaint. Removing the bit is desired to let the system know that it can free up some memory associated with layering and redirection. The code might look like this:*

```
// Remove WS_EX_LAYERED from this window styles
SetWindowLong(hwnd, 
              GWL_EXSTYLE,
              GetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_EXSTYLE) & ~WS_EX_LAYERED);

// Ask the window and its children to repaint
RedrawWindow(hwnd, 
             NULL, 
             NULL, 
             RDW_ERASE | RDW_INVALIDATE | RDW_FRAME | RDW_ALLCHILDREN);
```

I wrote a sample, and it does work after testing.
[image]

Comment: You removed the glass but the transparent background remains, do you know if its also possible to remove or hide it?

Comment: Disabling     SetLayeredWindowAttributes in the parent window will completely remove the background.

Using the above code simply disables transparent color. It will leave a white background by default.

Comment: @Daniel I have the latest news. In Windows 10 versions, using the DwmSetWindowAttribute function with DWMWA_TRANSITIONS_FORCEDISABLED parameters can cancel this effect. But it can't be done in Windows 11.